# building grpc protobuf take too long

Tags: docker, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using the following Dockerfile to install grpc on a build image, build a cpp microservice and put that into a runtime container.

https://github.com/npclaudiu/grpc-cpp-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

But the part that builds grpc/protobuf takes 2hours+ and that is for one service.

```
RUN echo "-- installing protobuf" && \
    cd /var/local/git/grpc/third_party/protobuf && \
    ./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-shared && \
    make -j$(nproc) && make -j$(nproc) check && make install && ldconfig
```

I see that all language implementations are compiled while I only need C++.

Is there any way to speed up this process? Are there debian or preferably alpine linux images with grpc and protocol buffers for c++ or all languages preinstalled?

Comment: Hi @Serve Laurijsseen,  I see on the https://github.com/npclaudiu/grpc-cpp-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile is based on https://hub.docker.com/r/grpc/cxx/dockerfile. Why you don't use `grpc/ccx` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an intermediate image. Split your Dockefile into 2 parts after these lines:

```
RUN echo "-- installing grpc" && \
cd /var/local/git/grpc && \
make -j$(nproc) && make install && make clean && ldconfig
```

build the first one once and for all (you'll wait 2hours only once), tag the image locally and use this image as your base image for the 2nd Dockerfile.